# Can Pycharm vim plugin support call function?

Tags: vim, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm2018.3.
I want to create some shortcut in my `~/.ideavimrc`
But it seems that pycharm vim plugin don't support `:call` command.
Here is my `~/.ideavimrc`

```
function! PrintVariable()
 if &filetype == 'python'
  :s/\v(\s*)(.*)/\1print("\2: ", \2)<CR>
 else
  :s/\v(\s*)(.*)/\1std::cout<<"\2"<<std::endl;<CR>
 endif
endfunction
map <space>p :call PrintVariable()<CR>
```

When I press `<space>p`, PyCharm says that

```
VIM-not an editor command: call
```

How can i triger a function in pycharm vim ?

Comment: You should submit a feature request at ideavim. btw, it doesn't support all vim attributes either.  E.g `&filetype`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IdeaVim doesn't fully support vim script. Here is a related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-506